# permission denied docker localhost

Tags: docker

i just started to learn docker...
and i faced this issue, of building image from dockerfile, run a container and trying to access to it!
so when i try to login localhost via ssh -p 12000 root@localhost,
it keeps saying permission denied even when i put abcd for password

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt update && apt -y upgrade
RUN apt install -y openssh-server
RUN apt-get install -y gcc
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
RUN echo 'root:abcd' | chpasswd
RUN sed -i 's/#*PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/PermitRootLogin yes/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
RUN sed -i 's@session\s*s*required\s*pam_loginuid.so@session optional pam_loginuid.so@g' /etc/pam.d/sshd

ENV NOTVISIBLE="in users profile"
RUN echo "export VISIBLE=now" >> /etc/profile

COPY hw.c /root

EXPOSE 22

CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
WORKDIR /root
RUN gcc -o root hw.c
```

Comment: Recommend reading [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, it is unclear as to what are you trying to achieve unless you provide the adjacent details as to how you started the container etc

Answer (score 1):

The best way to ssh to a container is by running this commands (this is for your ubuntu container)

`docker exec -ti <container_id> bash`

the container_id you can get it running `docker ps` if you didn't setup a fix name

Then you can remove all this lines

```
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
RUN echo 'root:abcd' | chpasswd
RUN sed -i 's/#*PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/PermitRootLogin yes/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
RUN sed -i 's@session\s*s*required\s*pam_loginuid.so@session optional pam_loginuid.so@g' /etc/pam.d/sshd

ENV NOTVISIBLE="in users profile"
RUN echo "export VISIBLE=now" >> /etc/profile

COPY hw.c /root

EXPOSE 22

CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

Remember also that everything you do by ssh on the container will be lost after the container is killed, so always better to add everything on the Dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it by deleting all remaining containers!